# How to extract applications as IPA files on iOS9?

Tags: ios, backup, jailbreak, restore

As of iOS9 Apple stopped allowing iTunes or any other application to backup apps to IPA files. When it comes time to do a restore, one must download all apps. This can either be done to iTunes or on the iOS device itself. The reason is because in iOS9 apps are "thinned" so that data only necessary for an iPad does not waste storage space on an iPhone.

Tools like iTools and iMazing and CopyTrans used to offer the functionality to backup apps to IPA, but have not added support for iOS9.

To question, how to backup apps to IPA so that they can be restored without downloading them again?

Comment: Developers can always remove their apps from the app store where it's impossible to download them again - so what happens if you paid a lot of money for a now-discontinued app on an iOS 9 (or later) device and need to move it to a new device?

Comment: @Dai In your example, moving to a new device, it is possible to move thinned apps if it is the same device model. Say, you break your iPhone7 screen and get a new iPhone7.

If, however, you want to move from an iPhone 6S to an iPhone 7 you must have the full unthinned app in iTunes.

Comment: So what can you do if you don't have the full IPA saved on your computer? So far it sounds like the only option is to demand a refund from Apple. But what about your data saved within the app itself?

Comment: It is not in your 'purchases'? Otherwise, you can ask Apple for a refund. The data for the app can be extracted from a backup, or the device with tools like `iTools` http://www.itools.cn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are jailbroken, there is a solution that can be batch scripted.

Install `sbutils` and `ipainstaller` from cydia

ssh to phone and run these commands:

`sbbundleids > backup.txt
while read line; do
ipainstaller -b $line
done < backup.txt`

and then to install the apps:

`ipainstaller *.ipa`

I tested a few and it allows to upgrade apps directly from app store without fuss. (same appleid, obviously)